# How to convert this sql code to Codigniter ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a row in table PRVO with four type of values : first, second, third, fourth

I want to count how many occurrences of first and how many of second and how many of third and how many of fourth I have and echo it like this:

```
First = 4
Second = 5
.....
```

I have the following code:

```
$anketadb->select('prvo');
$anketadb->from('anketadata');
$anketadb->group_by('prvo');
```

How can I add the count to have the result like I wrote above?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

Now I have situation:
MODEL:

```
$anketadb = $this->load->database('anketa',TRUE);

    $anketadb->select('prvo');
    $anketadb->from('anketadata');
    $anketadb->group_by('prvo');
$result =   $anketadb->get();

$result =   $result->result_array();

$count  =   array('povremeno' => 0, 'nikad' => 0, 'svakibroj' => 0, 'prodajemkupujem' => 0);

foreach($result as $row){
    switch($row){
        case 'povremeno' :  $count['povremeno']++; break;
        case 'nikad' : $count['nikad']++; break;
        case 'svakibroj' :  $count['svakibroj']++; break;
        case 'prodajemkupujem' : $count['prodajemkupujem']++; break;
    }
}
return $count;
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$this->load->model('anketerezultati_model');
    $data['count'] = $this->anketerezultati_model->prvo();
    $this->load->view('ankete/rezultatiankete', $data);
```

VIEW:

```
echo "povremeno".$count['povremeno'];
echo "nikad".$count['nikad'];
```

And result is 0 for both... I cannot find the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you need this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('anketadata');
$this->db->group_by('prvo');
$result =   $this->db->get();

//Result set
$result =   $result->result_array();
```

**UPDATE**

```
$count  =   array('first' => 0, 'second' => 0, 'third' => 0, 'fourth' => 0);

foreach($result as $row){

    switch($row['<fieldName>']){

        case 'first' :  $count['first']++; break;
        case 'second' : $count['second']++; break;
        case 'third' :  $count['third']++; break;
        case 'fourth' : $count['fourth']++; break;
    }
}
```

Finally you have occurrences of first.second.... at `$count` array. To use the number of occurrences `$count['first']` for second  `$count['second ']`.....

Comment: This is good solution bu I needed to put out row where is GROUP BY . Than it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Edit

```
$this->db->select('prvo');
$this->db->from('anketadata');
$this->db->group_by('prvo');
$query = $this->db->count_all_results();

return $query;
```

Comment: The point is the table what i have and one colum:

Column name : PRVO
Values what i put in : first, second, third, forth.

I want co count how many I that column i have from first, from second, from third, and from forth. Now do you understand my problem?

Comment: try MR Srinivas solution

Comment: I found a Solution from MR. with a little change, look the comment at his post.